# backup manager in plesk 12.doen't recognize my dumps folder

Tags: backup, restore, plesk

I find that in my repository "/psa/dumps/", ".discovered" folder is not found. So my backup is not valid. can I edit this directory.
Any help will be welcomed because all my websites are blocked

Comment: Why you are asking for /psa/dumps? Default dumps path is defined in for DUMP_D is /var/lib/psa/dumps

Comment: escuse me I omited the /var/lib/                                    I wanted to say /var/lib/psa/ So can I edit the ".discovered"

Comment: Well, if you know what service files there should be, yes you can add them to ".discovered" folder. But this is a service folder for internal purposes and format is not described in documentation.

Comment: thanks Oleg. i'll try to add them.